# Call dispatchKeyEvent to perform shape translation

Tags: java, javafx, timer, keyboard-events

I'm developing a simple Pong clone using JavaFX and I am having difficulty moving the paddle. I want to use a `KeyEventDispatcher` for this, and check for key presses during my `AnimationTimer` loop.

My `Main` class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Player m_pUser;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);
        ObservableList list = root.getChildren();

        KeyPressedChecker kpc = new KeyPressedChecker();

        m_pUser = new Player(kpc);

        list.add(m_pUser.getPaddleDrawable());

        GamePlayLoop gameLoop = new GamePlayLoop(m_pUser);
        gameLoop.start();

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My `GamePlayLoop` class:

```
public class GamePlayLoop extends AnimationTimer {

    Player m_pUser;

    public GamePlayLoop(Player p) {
        m_pUser = p;
    }

    public void handle(long now) {
        m_pUser.update();
    }
}
```

My `KeyPressedChecker` class:

```
public class KeyPressedChecker implements KeyEventDispatcher {

    private static boolean downPressed = false;

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
        synchronized (KeyPressedChecker.class) {
            switch (ke.getID()) {

                case KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED:
                    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                        downPressed = true;
                break;
                case KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED:
                    if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                        downPressed = false;
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isDownPressed() {
        synchronized (KeyPressedChecker.class) {
            return downPressed;
        }
    }
}
```

My `Player` class:

```
public class Player {

    private Paddle m_paddle;
    private KeyPressedChecker m_kpc;

    public Player(KeyPressedChecker kpc) {
        m_paddle = new Paddle();
    }

    public Rectangle getPaddleDrawable() {
        return m_paddle.getDrawable();
    }

    public void update() {
        if (m_kpc.isDownPressed())
            m_paddle.moveDown();
        m_paddle.update();
    }
}
```

And finally my `Paddle` class:

```
public class Paddle {

    private Rectangle m_rect;
    private double m_nPosY;

    public Paddle() {
        m_rect = new Rectangle(10, 60);
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        m_nPosY += 5;
    }

    public Rectangle getDrawable() {
        return m_rect;
    }

    public void update() {
        m_rect.setTranslateY(m_nPosY);
    }
}
```

My issue is that the paddle does not translate in the scene. In fact, `dispatchKeyEvent` is not called at all. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KeyEventDispatcher` is part of AWT, which is a toolkit that is completely independent of JavaFX. (Even if it were part of JavaFX, you just instantiate your implementing class, but never do anything with it...).

The way to do this in JavaFX is to register an event handler for `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` events with the scene.

So using your current design (approximately) you would do

```
public class KeyPressedChecker implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

    private boolean downPressed = false;

    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
        if (ke.getEventType() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
            downPressed = true ;
        } else if (ke.getEventType() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
            downPressed = false ;
        }   
    }

    public boolean isDownPressed() {
        return downPressed;
    }

}
```

In your `Player` class (I renamed fields to match proper [naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java))

```
public class Player {

    private Paddle paddle;
    private KeyPressedChecker kpc;

    public Player(KeyPressedChecker kpc) {
        this.paddle = new Paddle();
        this.kpc = kpc ;
    }

    public Rectangle getPaddleDrawable() {
        return paddle.getDrawable();
    }

    public void update() {
        if (kpc.isDownPressed())
            paddle.moveDown();
        paddle.update();
    }
}
```

and then everything is linked together with

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Player pUser;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);
        ObservableList list = root.getChildren();

        KeyPressedChecker kpc = new KeyPressedChecker();

        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.ANY, kpc);

        pUser = new Player(kpc);

        list.add(pUser.getPaddleDrawable());

        GamePlayLoop gameLoop = new GamePlayLoop(pUser);
        gameLoop.start();

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful and solved my issue, thank you very much! I understand renaming the class variables - my reasoning for naming them e.g. `m_pUser` is to signify a member variable (combined with Hungarian notation) to avoid having to ensure I write `this` to avoid name conflicts, as local variables will not include this 'm' in the name. Hope I explained myself properly.

Comment: @petehallw I understand the convention, which is used in other languages, but I strongly recommend you follow the Java conventions when writing Java (and similarly for other languages). It will make it easier for other programmers to read your code. Personally, FWIW, I hate `m_pUser` as it is impossible to internally vocalize it. (Please mark the answer as correct, if it solves the problem.)

Comment: Understandable, I'll consider it in the future. Marked as correct, thanks. Just out of interest, what do you mean by 'internally vocalize it'?

Comment: @petehallw When I read, I hear the words in my head (that's what I mean by "internally vocalize": maybe it's not a good description). That's as true for code as it is for reading normal prose. If the variable names are not names I can easily "say", then I find it hard to read (and consequently understand) the code. `m_pUser` is much harder to "say" when you read it than `pUser`. Obviously that is completely subjective.